# Dynamic SQL string returns NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

I am trying to construct a dynamic SQL statement and for some reason it is not returning the expected results. 
This is my query

```
DECLARE @user_script AS VARCHAR(MAX);



SELECT  @user_script += 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = '
        + SPACE(1) + '''' + [name] + '''' + ') BEGIN CREATE USER ' + SPACE(1)
        + QUOTENAME([name]) + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME([name])
        + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ' + QUOTENAME([default_schema_name])
        + SPACE(1) + 'END; '
FROM    sys.database_principals AS rm
WHERE   [type] IN ( 'U', 'S', 'G' )
        AND rm.default_schema_name IS NOT NULL;
PRINT ( @user_script );
```

My problem is that the print statement is not returning anything which I think  is because the `@user_script` variable is `NULL`.

To evaluate if my table is actually returning results I ran this query (exact copy of the above query without assigning it to a variable) and this query returns 10 rows

```
SELECT 'IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = '
        + SPACE(1) + '''' + [name] + '''' + ') BEGIN CREATE USER ' + SPACE(1)
        + QUOTENAME([name]) + ' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME([name])
        + ' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = ' + QUOTENAME([default_schema_name])
        + SPACE(1) + 'END; '
FROM    sys.database_principals AS rm
WHERE   [type] IN ( 'U', 'S', 'G' )
        AND rm.default_schema_name IS NOT NULL;
```

I tried replacing the function `QUOTENAME()` with quotes and `SPCACE()` with actual space but I got the same issue.

I finally checked to see if any of the returned results from the second query is `NULL`. But none of the rows was a `NULL`.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `DECLARE @user_script AS VARCHAR(MAX)='';`

Comment: I think you have to initialize `@user_script` or use `=` instead of `+=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a

```
SET @user_script = ''
```

on the line before your

```
select @user_script += ....
```

Comment: Yup. that's it. I am looking for a place to hide now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can start the select with

```
SELECT  @user_script =  ISNULL(@user_script, '') + ...
```